# Assign a hotkey to a powershell script's function

Tags: powershell, autoit

I want the script to run in the background and "paste" the variable's content in the currently active text field upon pressing a hotkey like CTRL+1. The code I have so far:

```
function Send($key)
{
    $wsh.SendKeys($key)
}

$wsh = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell

$c1 = "Text to be sent #1"
$c2 = "Text to be sent #2"
$c3 = "Text to be sent #3"
$c4 = "Text to be sent #4"
$c0 = "Text to be sent #5"

switch ($check)
{
    1 {Send($c1)}
    2 {Send($c2)}
    3 {Send($c3)}
    4 {Send($c4)}
    0 {Send($c0)}
    default {Sleep(1)}
}
```

I tried searching and can't find any working solution.
I currently use AutoIt script with the similair functionality, although I didn't write this one and unfortunately don't know the author.

```
#include < Misc.au3 >

Func _SendEx($ss, $warn = "")
    Local $iT = TimerInit()

    While _IsPressed("10") Or _IsPressed("11") Or _IsPressed("12")
        If $warn <> "" And TimerDiff($iT) > 1000 Then
            MsgBox(262144, "Avertissement", $warn)
        EndIf
        Sleep(50)
    WEnd
    Send($ss)
EndFunc;==>_SendEx

HotKeySet ("^1", "c1")
HotKeySet ("^2", "c2")
HotKeySet ("^3", "c3")
HotKeySet ("^4", "c4")
HotKeySet ("^0", "c0")

While True
    Sleep (10000)
WEnd

Func c1 ()
    _SendEx ("text 1")
EndFunc

Func c2 ()
    _SendEx ("text 2")
EndFunc

Func c3 ()
    _SendEx ("text 3")
EndFunc

Func c4 ()
    _SendEx ("text 4")
EndFunc

Func c0 ()
    _SendEx ("text 0")
EndFunc
```

I'd like to recreate that in powershell, how to assign a hotkey to that function?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there is no native way to perform that.

If you really want to proceed with this approach then I would recommend you to put the function in a **.ps1**

Then, call the script using a batch script (**.bat**)

Finally, you can set a hot key to that batch file that you can register when the windows boot up each time.

Step by step approach with screenshot is below:

[Creating Shortcuts](https://johnmj.wordpress.com/2010/11/11/sharepoint-2010-and-localhost-2/)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to emulate a macro button similar to what many logitech keyboards have. If you are trying to run a script to listen for global keystrokes and then fire a paste when a certain combination is pressed you may need to look into pinvoke from user32.dll and kernel32.dll specifically [SetWindowsHookEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990(v=vs.85).aspx), [FindWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633499(v=vs.85).aspx), [FindWindowEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633500(v=vs.85).aspx), [BringWindowToTop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632673(v=vs.85).aspx), and [Systems.Windows.Forms.SendKeys](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.aspx)

In a nutshell you should be able to set a hook with SetWindowsHookEx and WH_KEYBOARD_LL, in the handler use FindWindow/FindWindowEx to locate the target window, use BringWindowToTop, then send the ^V key via SendKeys to paste into the field. There are plenty of keylogger [examples](https://hinchley.net/2013/11/03/creating-a-key-logger-via-a-global-system-hook-using-powershell/) for powershell that can show you how to use pinvoke and set the hooks.